# How to refesh oAuth2 token + spring security

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, jhipster

I have implemented Spring security with oAuth2. I want to refresh our access token before it expire. Please help me how to made request for refresh my access token.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a POST request to *oauth/token*, see the following AngularJS snippet:

```
function ajaxRefreshToken(refresh_token) {
        return $injector.get('$http')
            .post(
                'oauth/token',
                'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + refresh_token,
                {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('***' + ':' + '***')
                }
            });
    }
```

or, with cURL:

```
curl -s -u $CLIENT_ID:$SECRET \
  'http://$HOST/oauth/token'  \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token='$REFRESH_TOKEN
```

Comment: Hi @francesecou, I am getting this with request {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}.

Comment: Hi I am getting this exception now {"error":"server_error","error_description":"UserDetailsService is required."}

Comment: Are you replacing the two *** with your clientId and clientSecret?

Comment: @sdoxsee: yes, I've added a cURL example to my previous comment

Comment: @charnjeet-singh: please write the full stacktrace

Comment: Yes, I have replace *** with client id and clientSecret. But getting {"error":"server_error","error_description":"UserDetailsService is required."}. I have called from reset client

Comment: @charnjeet-singh please write the full stacktrace from the logs. Are you using Spring Security OAuth 2.0.7 if so, check this issue: [Refresh token request doesn't work, when used with Spring Security OAuth 2.0.7](https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/issues/19)

Comment: Hi Francescou, I am not using UserDetailsService . I am using then AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider class because I have getting my user from some other api using retrieveUser method.

Answer (score 0):

```
oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=[id]&client_secret=[secret]&refresh_token=[your refresh token]
```

Send request like above.You should add client details with the request.

Comment: Hi I am getting this exception now {"error":"server_error","error_description":"UserDetailsService is required."}